# Switching referencing format Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I have a .bib library which I usually view in Jabref. Alternatively I can open it as a text file and the references are provided in the following format:

```
@Book{olson1967,
  Title                    = {Music, physics and engineering},
  Author                   = {Olson, Harry Ferdinand},
  Publisher                = {Courier Dover Publications},
  Year                     = {1967},
  Volume                   = {1769}
}
```

For a journal submission I need the references in the following format:

```
\bibitem[{Feynman(1954)}]{feyn54}
  \bibinfo{author}{Feynman, R.~P.} 
  (\bibinfo{year}{1954}).
  \bibinfo{title}{Positrons are electrons traveling backwards in time}, 
  \bibinfo{journal}{Phys.\ Rev.} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{94}},
  \bibinfo{pages}{262}.
```

They don't accept a .bib library with submission.

Does anyone know a way to get my references in to the required format (other than manually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the document and run BibTeX as usual. Then open the `.bbl` file and copy the entries into your document, removing the `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` commands at this stage.

Comment: Thanks! That was easier than I thought - really glad I asked.